# GraphQL Root Query: Same schema, different types

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm pretty new to GraphQL and within my root query I have two fields that are very similar aside from their "type" property, that I would like to combine.

`allPosts` returns an array of post objects, while `post` returns a single post.

Each field is using the same schema, and the loaders/resources are being determined within those respective fields based on the argument passed in.

```
const RootQuery = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    description: 'Root Query',
    fields: {
      allPosts: {
          type: new graphql.GraphQLList(postType),
          args: {
              categoryName: {
                  type: graphql.GraphQLString
              }
          },
          resolve: (root, args) => resolver(args)
      },
      post: {
          type: postType,
          args: {
              slug: {
                  type: graphql.GraphQLString
              }
          },
          resolve: (root, args) => resolver(args)
      },
});
```

Is it possible to combine these two fields into one and have the type determined by the argument passed in or another variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "Each field is using the same schema"? Why do you want to combine these two fields when they have different purposes?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't!

Once you define a field as `GraphQLList`, you always get an array. There is no chance that you suddenly get an `object` instead of `array of`. 
Same apply to other case when you define field as `GraphQLObjectType` (or any other scalar type) and you want get an array as result.

Those two fields have really different purposes.

Anyway, you can always add a limit logic to your `allPosts` field and limit the result to one. But, nevertheless you get always array with only one post